# What's default DTD if not mentioned in doctype declaration?

Tags: html

In my page, the doctype is declared as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

no DTD is explicitly specified.
I wonder in IE which DTD will be defaulted?

seems it does not behave the same as

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
```

since my table in the page was broken after I added the loose.dtd.
Can anyone help explain this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the SGML standard, your document type declaration specifies a Document Type Definition by naming it, as registered by the W3C. However, by the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.2), a document must have one of three alternative document type declarations, and all of them contain a URL, too.

This is as such just theory, since browsers don’t actually read DTDs. They treat document type declarations just as magic strings, in [doctype sniffing](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/). However, in most browsers, the choice of a browser’s mode is affected by the presence or absence of a URL in that magic string for HTML 4.01 Transitional. When it is absent, they operate in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html). When it is present, most browsers operate in “standards mode” or “almost standards mode”.

Quirks Mode means a large number of different quirks, so the effect of switching from it to “standards mode” may imply just about anything (varying from no effect to complete disaster). Such a switch generally requires a careful check, if not rewrite, of the entire document.

Answer (score 5):

Your mileage will vary depending on browser and version, but here's the short of it:

To the best of my knowledge, browsers don't actually go to any effort to fetch and make use of the dtd in the URL, or validate the code in any way. Resultingly, your webpage will work "fine" without a doctype declaration, with a broken doctype declaration, and in a number of other broken forms.

When not running your code through a validator, the major reason for providing a doctype definition at the top of your code is to pull browsers out of quirks mode and into standards compliance mode, ala the historical disaster with IE < 7 ...

*It's a little bit outside of the scope to lecture on quirks and standards mode here, so the curious should head over to wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode*

Web browsers use their own relatively arbitrary standards to switch modes based on the doctype. What you are likely encountering is IE in **quirks mode** when your DTD lacks a URL, and **standards mode** when you add the URL.

You should probably aim to include the full declaration, including the URL, and run your code through the W3C validator [1] for good measure.

Fix the rendering problems with valid code and a full doctype [2]. Quirks mode was only ever intended for backwards compatibility so that unmaintained websites will continue to render as expected for as long as possible.
If your web page only renders as expected in quirks mode, **your web page is broken**.

**Sidenote: you should seriously question why you are using 4.01 transitional in 2013.**

[1] http://validator.w3.org/ 
[2] http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer, @Kiirani. I am working on a legacy web project which was developed around 10 years ago, so you know I cannot avoid using 4.01 transitional doctype as it's defined in the page template for the whole web site consistently.

Comment: I just created a static html and tested the possible behavior of IE you've mentioned, you're right about that. If lack of DTD URL, IE is in quirks mode and otherwise in standard mode. My testing is in IE8.
However, for now, I cannot modify the doctype to include the URL, since it will break the page rendering, especially table elements...