# Is there any way to get Chrome to do CSS transitions with letter-spacing smoothly?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I am attempting to have a nice CSS transition for letter-spacing property.

It looks great in Firefox and Internet explorer 10 (something finally works as expected in IE. Omg, right?)

But it doesn't work in Chrome or Opera. In Chrome it is a series of jitters, so it goes from 2px to 1px to 0. No smooth-pixel rendering like in IE/Firefox.

Is there any way to make Chrome render it smoothly?

Here is a simple example:

```
p {
    letter-spacing:2px; 
    -webkit-transition: letter-spacing, 1s;
    -moz-transition: letter-spacing, 1s;
    -o-transition: letter-spacing, 1s;
    transition: letter-spacing, 1s;
}
p:hover {letter-spacing:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aDhRz/

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome 29.

Comment: Kind of works in Chrome 29.0.1547.65, but it's not so much an animation as a series of jitters

Comment: Jeez. I'm not sure there's a good answer for this. Everything I've tried in Chrome gives choppy animations, even using straight jQuery as well as the jQuery Transit library, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/meub/aDhRz/6/). I think Chrome animates letter-spacing pixel by pixel so there's only three states 2px, 1px, 0px. Other browsers must animate with more states between pixels.

Comment: Think you're totally right @meub, this strikes me as a bug. Had a look on the chromium bug tracker and couldn't find a bug relating to this. Anyone want to do the honours?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly right, it's not an animation, but a series of jitters. I read somewhere something about sub-pixel rendering, other browsers do it, but not Chrome, which explains the 2px... 1px.. 0px transition. I don't think there is a fix :(

Comment: I'm not sure that's the correct meaning of sub-pixel rendering. I don't think it is a bug, I think it's the correct implementation. Look at the border in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/aDhRz/7/) or the top position in this one (http://jsfiddle.net/aDhRz/8/). It's not only the letter-spacing property, it's all properties.

Comment: @Adam it isn't correct, css transition is meant to be pixel-smooth rendering, try your fiddle in firefox or IE10.

Comment: @user2413333 - well, it is "pixel" smooth. Not sub-pixel. And you're right, letter-spacing does work as expected in Firefox, however the border and top transitions are equally bad in Chrome/Firefox. Odd indeed.

Comment: I suggest you guys read [this post](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) from Paul Irish. It's not related to letter spacing, but to old-style CSS transforms vs. new style and how it affects performance/smooothing.

Comment: @Adam It's not really pixel-smooth if a single step of the animation changes the width of a block (i.e. the thing anyone actually cares about in this scenario) by more than one pixel. Except in uselessly pedantic sense of the word, i.e. "well **something** changes in one-pixel increments" - you could use that sort of anti-logic to excuse a lot of weird behaviours.

Comment: Yes, having something work in IE10 is far more shocking than having something not work in Chrome. /s

Comment: Been fiddling with float px letter-spacing. And Firefox renders a 0.5px letter-spacing just fine (at least it's something between 0 and 1px), whereas Chrome seems to floor the values to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is now fixed in Blink (powering the Chrome layout engine) but not yet rolled out in stable Chrome. But you can see it's working fine now in Chrome Canary.

Until it's available for everyone, I don't think there will be a workaround without a JavaScript solution using `canvas`. We're lucky Chrome auto-updates :)

**Blink fix**: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=153727

Seems that Google is taking Blink development seriously, because this bug exists in WebKit since 2008, and it's still not fixed.

**WebKit bug report**: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20606

Answer (score 1):

If you are having performance problems in Chrome you could try forcing the element onto the `GPU` where it is rendered on it's own layer.  This can be done using `translate3d`

**Example**

```
p{
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

It is also worth using chrome dev tools timeline to narrow down what the problem is.

[Performance profiling with the Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline)

Comment: This is an AMAZING HACK!

Answer (score 0):

In your example It's not possible to get it smooth as the transition decreases by `1px` on each step, it works just like any other css property that uses pixels, if you increase the `px` you will see it does actually render smoothly like in this example **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aDhRz/21/)**

If you add such a minor change in pixels to another pixel property with a long duration you will see the same **Step visibility** effect like in this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VusAs/)**

So, the only way this would be possible is if you could tell chrome to change the step to something like `0.1px` but unfortunately you cannot do that.

So saying all that and finding out that it does the same on every property if you add that kind of (change + transition) combination I would say this is **not** a bug.

Comment: No, it is not a bug. It's just very clear that chrome decrements by the pixel and not the the tenth of a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using em instead of px, its not perfect but its a improvement. Also faster speeds dont seem as jumpy.

```
p {
letter-spacing:0.5em; 
-webkit-transition: letter-spacing, 0.5s;
-moz-transition: letter-spacing, 0.5s;
-o-transition: letter-spacing, 0.5s;
transition: letter-spacing, 0.5s;
}
p:hover {
letter-spacing:0em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Cvd/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

before your  tag. This must solve your problem.

Reasons to use this is explained below by [Jukka K. Korpela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084437/jukka-k-korpela) in a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949124/whats-default-dtd-if-not-mentioned-in-doctype-declaration).

> By the SGML standard, your document type declaration specifies a
>   Document Type Definition by naming it, as registered by the W3C.
>   However, by the HTML 4.01 spec, a document must have one of three
>   alternative document type declarations, and all of them contain a URL,
>   too.
>
> This is as such just theory, since browsers don’t actually read DTDs.
>   They treat document type declarations just as magic strings, in
>   doctype sniffing. However, in most browsers, the choice of a browser’s
>   mode is affected by the presence or absence of a URL in that magic
>   string for HTML 4.01 Transitional. When it is absent, they operate in
>   Quirks Mode. When it is present, most browsers operate in “standards
>   mode” or “almost standards mode”.
>
> Quirks Mode means a large number of different quirks, so the effect of
>   switching from it to “standards mode” may imply just about anything
>   (varying from no effect to complete disaster). Such a switch generally
>   requires a careful check, if not rewrite, of the entire document.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
p {
    letter-spacing:2px; 
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
p:hover {letter-spacing:0;}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't use a little bit jQuery to solve this. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aDhRz/

```
(function(){
  $('p').hover(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('zero');
  });
})();
```

And css

```
.zero{
  letter-spacing:0;
}
```